# Show that the series $\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}a_{k}b_{k}x^{k}$ converges absolutely

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

*This is no homework, it's part of a sample exam which can be found here: http://www2.mathematik.hu-berlin.de/~gaggle/S15/MATHINFO/UEBUNG/nachholklausur.pdf*

> Given: Two power series $\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}a_{k}x^{k}, \sum_{k =0}^{\infty}b_{k}x^{k}$ with radius (of convergence) $r_{a}, r_{b} \in
> \mathbb{R}$.
>
> Show that the series $\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}a_{k}b_{k}x^{k}$ converges
>   absolutely for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ with $|x| < r_{a}r_{b}$
>
> Does divergence follow from that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ with $|x|
> > r_{a}r_{b}$?

To show that the series $\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}a_{k}b_{k}x^{k}$ converges
absolutely, we need to show that

$$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \left | \frac{z_{k+1}}{z_{k}} \right | = 0$$

$\Rightarrow$

$$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \left | \frac{a_{k+1}b_{k+1}}{a_{k}b_{k}} \right | = 0$$

$$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \left | \left (\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_{k}} \right ) \left ( \frac{b_{k+1}}{b_{k}} \right ) \right | = 0$$

$$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \left | \left (\frac{a_{k}+a_{k-1}}{a_{k}} \right ) \left ( \frac{b_{k}+b_{k-1}}{b_{k}} \right )\right | = 0$$

$$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \left |\left ( 1+ \frac{a_{k-1}}{a_{k}} \right ) \left (1+\frac{b_{k-1}}{b_{k}} \right ) \right | = 0$$

And here I stopped because I don't know how to continue this : /

I'm also not sure if this is the right way to go because I haven't really used the given info with $|x| < r_{a}r_{b}$.

How is a task like that done when there isn't really a series given?

It may have been more clear for me if there was a series and a radius of convergence with a number...

Comment: I think you will need the root test, not the ratio test. Divergence does not follow if $|x|\gt r_ar_b$. For pick $a_k=0$ when $b_k\ne 0$, and vice-versa, with suitable values otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ratio test will prove that the series is absolutely convergent if the absolute value of the result is less than $1$. This is true because the series will eventually grow smaller than an arbitrary convergent geometric series. Therefore, since we know that series a and b converges with $|x|<r_a,r_b$ respectively, we also know that as $lim_{k>\infty}$, $\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}r_a=1$ and that $\frac{b_{k+1}}{b_k}r_b=1$. When we apply the ratio test to the third series, we get $\frac{a_{k+1}b_{k+1}}{a_kb_k}r_ar_b$. This is equivalent to the product of the ratios of the first two series as $k$ approaches infinity, which is one. Hence, when $x < r_ar_b$, the ratio of the third series becomes less than one, meaning that it is absolutely convergent. Additionally, we have shown that the radius of convergence is when $|x| = r_ar_b$, so the series is divergent when $x > r_ar_b$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer!